# jQuery: How to display the appropriate value in the right textatrea

Tags: jquery

Ok, this is maybe a common or simple matter for you but I'm stuck with it, really.

I thought the problem has been resolved but there is one thing when each of the radio button clicked in sequence (start from number 1-3) will appear in the textbox value perfectly but when clicked randomly (start from number 3 - 1 / 2 - 3 - 1) the first value that appears is always in the first textbox.

How to display the appropriate value in the right `textatrea` (when its checked number 3 will appear in the textbox value on number 3).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwWb2/2/)

HTML

```
<form name = "form" id = "id_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num1" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num1" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "display1" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num2" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num2" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "display2" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num3" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num3" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "display3" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){
        $(":radio:checked").each(function(i){
            var num = i + 1;
        if($(this).val() == "1") {
            $("input:text[name=display"+num+"]").val("1");
        }else{
            $("input:text[name=display"+num+"]").val("3");
        }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Some code, HTML, better fiddle?

Comment: I don't know why can't put my link on my question. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/RwWb2/

Comment: It's not clear what you need.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question, not just a link.

Comment: @AmitJoki Thank you for editing my link. Now I know how to add the code next to the link pffft~

Comment: there is a problem with your fiddle where textarea i cant see anywhere  textarea

Comment: @M.chaudhry OP means textbox

Comment: @M.chaudhry updated my code above

Comment: I'd hope he means a text-`input`, which is a real HTML element.

Comment: well happens with beginners no problems:)

Comment: @ESKA Why you are iterating through all the `checked` radio input?

Comment: ccheck and tell what u want or did i get you right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class="display" in your text inputs

```
<form name = "form" id = "id_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num1" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num1" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="display" name = "display1" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num2" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num2" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="display" name = "display2" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num3" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num3" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="display" name = "display3" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Change your JS to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("input:radio").change(function(){

            if($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".display").val("1");
        }else{
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".display").val("3");
        }
        console.log($(this).closest(".display").val());
        });
    });
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/RwWb2/3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are iterating over the `checked` radio `<input>`. Instead you need to find the parent index of the current checked radio element.

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){
    //will find correct index and increment it with 1
    var index = ($(this).closest('tr').index() + 1);

    if($(this).val() == "1") {
        $("input:text[name=display"+index+"]").val("1");
    }else{
        $("input:text[name=display"+index+"]").val("3");
    }

});
```

Replace variable `num` with `index`

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RwWb2/4/)</kbd>

Comment: because without it would not get the value in the element input:text, so I tried to iterating over the :radio:checked. This is also perfect, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want 1 2 3 in each input text according to checkbox below is code

```
<form name = "form" id = "id_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num1" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num1" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="display" name = "display1" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num2" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num2" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="display1" name = "display2" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num3" id = "Yes" value = "1" />YES</td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "num3" id = "No" value = "0" />NO</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="display2" name = "display3" id = "display" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("input:radio").change(function(){

            if($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".display").val("1");
        }if($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".display1").val("2");
        }if($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".display2").val("3");
        }
    else{
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".display,.display1,.display2").val("0");
        }
        console.log($(this).closest(".display").val());
        });
    });
```

credict goes to dimitris :)

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maree_chaudhry/V8rCt/

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware that you have several elements sharing the same `id`, which invalidates your HTML (an `id` ***must*** be unique with the document).

That said, once the `id`s are removed (since they're unnecessary), I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that);
    $that.closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val(that.value == 1 ? 1 : 3);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RwWb2/5/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).